# Android NullPointerException when using Theme

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme

I've got a problem where I dont see the problem.
I want to hide the ActionBar in one of my Activities in my Android app (I use Minimum SDK Level 8)
When I add:

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar"
```

to my Manifest File i get an NullPointerException once i start this Activity, if I don't use it, there is no Problem.
This is a snippet out of my Manifest

```
        <activity
           android:name="com.example.freivonangst.Breath2Activity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_breath2"
           android:parentActivityName="com.example.freivonangst.MainActivity"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
           <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value="com.example.freivonangst.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Fun Fact: In another project using this Theme is no problem. I just can't figure out what's wrong.
Do you fine people have any idea?

//Edit Stacktrace

```
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2100    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2125 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 140    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1227  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4898    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1006 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 773 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

oddly LogCat doesnt print any error oO
only these 2 warnings

```
    07-15 22:36:55.735: W/ActivityThread(16095): Application com.example.freivonangst is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    07-15 22:42:53.375: W/dalvikvm(16095): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7: Landroid/support/v4/app/NavUtils;.navigateUpFromSameTask (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
```

//Edit 2
I know it's a NullPointerExeption because the debugger said it is one, there are 3 Variables:
this --> android.app.ActivityThread@40cdf710
e --> java.lang.NullPointerException
activity --> com.example.freivonangst.Breath2Activity@40d269d0

Comment: what does the exception look like?

Comment: Please add your log cat output

Comment: how did you find out you are getting a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

The DeviceDefault was added in API 14, so you'll get an error on any platform below that. That being said, no idea how it was working in your other project.

Comment: I was trying it on my 4.1.2 Mobile, so it should, at least work there. SHouldn't it?

Comment: it should, yes. what kind of device? have you tried it on other devices? there is always the chance that the manufacturer has modified the rom (specifically for themeing) in a way that removed some of the built-in styles.

Comment: I used my Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Virtual Google Nexus One (Version 4.2.2)